# Connecting to cassandra cluster with kerberos using java driver

Tags: cassandra, kerberos, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I followed the instructions from the following datastax post - [Accessing secure DSE clusters](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/accessing-secure-dse-clusters-with-cql-native-protocol)

This is my code snippet -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
KerberosAuthenticatedClient client = new KerberosAuthenticatedClient();     
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/krb5.config");
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/DseClient.config");    
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).withAuthProvider(new DseAuthProvider()).build();
session = cluster.connect();
```

This is my DseClient File -

```
DseClient {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
     useKeyTab=true
   doNotPrompt=true
     keyTab="C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/dse.keytab"
     principal="rock@MY.COM";
};
```

And This is my krb5.conf -

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = MY.COM
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true

[realms]
MY.COM = {
kdc = x.x.x.x
admin_server = x.x.x.x
}

[domain_realm]
.my.com = MY.COM
my.com = MY.COM
```

I have installed kerberos on my client machine and also on the servers too. But when I run I get the following error :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

at com.datastax.driver.core.sasl.KerberosAuthenticator.loginSubject(KerberosAuthenticator.java:113)
at com.datastax.driver.core.sasl.KerberosAuthenticator.<init>(KerberosAuthenticator.java:94)
at com.datastax.driver.core.sasl.DseAuthProvider.newAuthenticator(DseAuthProvider.java:52)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.initializeTransport(Connection.java:163)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:131)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:59)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:444)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:205)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:168)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:81)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:812)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.access$100(Cluster.java:739)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:67)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:708)
at KerberosAuthenticatedClient.connect(KerberosAuthenticatedClient.java:19)
at KerberosAuthenticatedClient.main(KerberosAuthenticatedClient.java:45)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source)
at com.datastax.driver.core.sasl.KerberosAuthenticator.loginSubject(KerberosAuthenticator.java:109)
... 16 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the stacktrace is complaining that it is unable to find any credentials for the OS user executing the request. This is usually cause by one of three conditions:

1. not setting the location of the JAAS config correctly (which causes us to fall back to the default of using the TGT cache & often leading to 2.)
2. an empty local ticket cache (when not using a keytab)
3. credentials for the specified principal missing from the keytab

The first thing I'd check is that you have set the `java.security.auth.login.config` system property to the location of your JAAS config file (the DseClient file) correctly? 
If you have and are still seeing the error, you can check the contents of the keytab with `klist -e -t -k /path/to/keytab`

Another useful tip for debugging is to set `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` which will dump lots of detailed info to stdout.

Comment: I have tried with the debug option and this is what I see - >>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): MY.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): rock
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 64; type: 18
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): MY.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): rock
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 48; type: 17
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): MY.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): rock
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 56; type: 16

Comment: >>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): MY.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): rock
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 48; type: 23
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): MY.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): rock
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 40; type: 8
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): MY.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): rock
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 40; type: 3

Comment: Java config name: C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/krb5.config
Loaded from Java config
Added key: 3version: 3
Found unsupported keytype (8) for rock@MY.COM
Added key: 23version: 3
Added key: 16version: 3
Added key: 17version: 3
Found unsupported keytype (18) for rock@MY.COM
Ordering keys wrt default_tkt_enctypes list
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 17 16 23 1 3.

Comment: >>> KrbAsReq creating message
getRealmFromDNS: trying usac.MY.com
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Cannot locate default realm
 at com.datastax.driver.core.sasl.KerberosAuthenticator.loginSubject(KerberosAuthenticator.java:113)

Comment: The error at the end of that output regarding getRealmFromDNS suggests issues with host resolution. See http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-current/doc/admin/princ_dns.html for some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the service principle to dse/hostname@REALM from cassandra/hostname@REALM and it worked. I am not sure why the java program which I ran from my windows machine was taking the service principle as dse/hostname instead of cassandra/hostname

Comment: because that's the default https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.0/driver-dse/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/auth/DseAuthProvider.java#L30
This isn't in the javadoc for version 1.0 of the driver as the Kerberos components are in a DSE specific branch. With version 2.0, this has moved into a new submodule and so will be included (once the driver hits GA or a new RC is released and the Javadoc is updated).